# How do you edit the connection to the TFS server in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am currently connecting to the TFS server via IP.

In Visual Studio 2012, how can I edit this to use it's new domain name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Team Explorer
2. Click drop down at top of team explorer (under the
   search box and navigation buttons etc)
3. Projects & My Teams
4. Connect to Team Projects
5. Click Servers...
6. Add

Comment: and how can I tell VS that my project has to use this new server ? VS keeps trying to connect to the old address